# receiving a small refund

Tags: micropayments

I was joining a website and asked  pay with bitcoin and they say they will refund a tiny bit back to me and the last 4 digits will be my passcode.

Is this even possible? how would there computer know what code or wallet they would be sending it back to.

As from what i know from selling and receiving bitcoin always needs a new code which they haven't asked for.

Comment: I would never "join" a website if I found any of their financial arrangements unusual, surprising or confusing. That's a red flag. Others may disagree.

Comment: This sounds very unusual. Barring further details, I would be quite wary of this being some sort of scam.